Pagination for GridView using SwiftUI
I create a pagination screen using TMDb api in SwiftUI for GridView :
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if(viewModel.movies.isEmpty) {
            loadingOrErrorView
        } else {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: Constants.gridItemSize))]) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.movies, id: \.self.id) { movie in
                        MovieColumn(movie: movie).onAppear {
                            if movie == viewModel.movies.last, viewModel.hasMoreData {
                                Task {
                                    await viewModel.loadMoreData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
                loadingOrErrorView
            }
        }
    }.task {
        await viewModel.loadMoreData()
    }
}
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private var loadingOrErrorView: some View {
        switch viewModel.viewState {
        case .loading:
            ProgressView()
        case .failure(let error):
            errorView(error: error)
        case .idle:
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
    
    private func errorView(error: Error) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Text(error.localizedDescription)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.loadMoreData()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Retry")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
    }

And here is my ViewModel :
@Observable
class PaginationViewModel {
    var movies: [Movie] = []
    var hasMoreData = true
    var viewState: ViewState = .idle
    
    @ObservationIgnored
    private var currentPage = 1
    
    @ObservationIgnored
    private let networkService: NetworkService
    
    init(networkService: NetworkService) {
        self.networkService = networkService
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func loadMoreData() async {
        guard viewState != .loading && hasMoreData else { return }
        self.viewState = .loading
        do {
            let request = TMDbRequest(path: .movies, page: currentPage)
            let newItems: TMDbWrapper = try await networkService.perform(request: request)
            self.movies.append(contentsOf: newItems.movies)
            self.currentPage += 1
            self.hasMoreData = newItems.movies.count == Constants.PAGE_SIZE
            self.viewState = .idle
        } catch {
            self.viewState = .failure(error: error)
        }
    }
    
    private struct Constants {
        static let PAGE_SIZE = 20
    }
}

enum ViewState: Equatable {
    case idle
    case loading
    case failure(error: Error)
    
    static func == (lhs: ViewState, rhs: ViewState) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.idle, .idle): return true
        case (.loading, .loading): return true
        case (.failure(error: _), .failure(error: _)): return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
}

As you see I have implemented loading and error view logic in two different place. One for initial state and one for loading next page. Is there any solution to improve this logic while using GridView? I also wonder if you have a more optimize solution for Pagination in SwiftUI?
Source code : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/Pagination-Assignment/tree/main
